# Fix required fo plotting Woodie's Pivots in Pin Script TradingView

Tags: pine-script

the following is my pine script code of "Woodie's Pivot Points" for trading view platform. Though the code is error free, but it's not plotting itself on the chart and I am failing to identify the problem. Please help me to resolve this particular issue.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Woodie's Pivot Points", shorttitle = "WPP", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500)
//Inputs
PlotWP = input.bool(title = "Plot Woodie's Pivots?", defval=true)
resp = input(title="Resolution", defval="D")
isessp = session.regular
tp = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session=isessp)
igapsp = barmerge.gaps_off
yesterdayHighp = request.security(tp,resp,high[1], gaps=igapsp, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
yesterdayLowp = request.security(tp,resp,low[1], gaps=igapsp, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
todayOpenp = request.security(tp,resp,open, gaps=igapsp, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Calculation
wpr = yesterdayHighp - yesterdayLowp
wpm = yesterdayHighp + yesterdayLowp + 2 * todayOpenp
wpr1 = (2 * wpm) - yesterdayLowp
wpr2 = wpm + (yesterdayHighp - yesterdayLowp)
wpr3 = yesterdayHighp + 2 * (wpm - yesterdayLowp)
wpr4 = wpr3 + wpr
wps1 = (2 * wpm) - yesterdayHighp
wps2 = wpm - (wpr1 - wps1)
wps3 = yesterdayLowp - 2 * (yesterdayHighp - wpm)
wps4 = wps3 - wpr 

//Plot
plot(PlotWP ? wpm : na, "Woodie's Pivot Median", color.black, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wpr1 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Resistance_1", color.olive, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wps1 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Support_1", color.maroon, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wpr2 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Resistance_2", color.olive, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wps2 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Support_2", color.maroon, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wpr3 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Resistance_3", color.olive, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wps3 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Support_3", color.maroon, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wpr4 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Resistance_4", color.olive, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(PlotWP ? wps4 : na, "Woodie's Pivot Support_4", color.maroon, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

'Your' script works. 
For example, choose BTC, timeframe 1D, and you will see the plotting :
[image]